# How many security holes were discovered in the original version of Windows XP?

Tags: windows, known-vulnerabilities

In order to steer our future, it is important to understand our past. Now as the end of Windows XP draws near it would be interesting to see how the worlds most popular operating system fared security-wise. Specifically, how many known vulnerabilities were present in the original RTM version of Windows XP?

Comment: Edited as we have no real way to know how many vulnerabilities were present, just which ones have been discovered and published.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In total, across all service packs, there were [721 KNOWN vulnerabilities](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/739/Microsoft-Windows-Xp.html?vendor_id=26).

[image: graph: Vulnerabilities By Year; Vulnerabilities By Type]